# Pinia w/ Vue3: Using Actions in template returns funcName is not a function

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Using a Pinia action from within the template in Vue3 gives

> Uncaught TypeError: $setup.[storeName].[actionName] is not a function

Am I doing something wrong or is it expected behaviour. It doesn't seem that anybody else having the same issue. Google search didn't reveal anything.

I'm using the new  components

Comment: Got the same issue. 1st time I've used pinia

Comment: Do control + R  and should work. Can happen when the changes are not loaded upon save

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this when I mistakenly tried to destructure actions as well as state and getters with `storeToRefs`, after not reading this bit from [the Pinia docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#using-the-store) carefully enough:

> In order to extract properties from the store while keeping its reactivity, you need to use `storeToRefs()`. It will create refs for every reactive property. This is useful when you are only using state from the store but not calling any action. Note you can destructure actions **directly from the store** *[emphasis added]* as they are bound to the store itself too.

So given this template —

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="thing in things" :key="thing">{{ frob(thing) }}</li>
  <li>
</template>
```

— and this store —

```js
const useStore = defineStore("store", {
  state: () => ({ things: ["1", "2", "3"], }),
  actions: { frob(arg) { return `frobbed ${arg}`; } },
});
const store = useStore();
```

— if you try to destructure both `things` and `frob` with `storeToRefs`, you'll get `TypeError: $setup.frob is not a function`. Actions, unlike state and getters, should be destructured directly from the store object:

```js
// wrong
const { things, frob } = storeToRefs(store);

// right
const { things } = storeToRefs(store)
const { frob } = store
```

Note that in Chrome the error will show up as `Uncaught (in promise)`, while in Safari it will show up as `Unhandled Promise Rejection`.

Comment: You've enabled me to also not read the docs. I appreciate you and also you're an enabler of my disease.

Comment: @person13 eh, nobody can be expected to read them cover to cover, or if they do to remember them.

Answer (score 4):

```
const users = defineStore('users', {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
})
```

some times using the same name for two stores causes this issue.

Comment: I encountered this situation when I set the same name

Answer (score 0):

Was also running into this, for me the fix was to **check the structure** of the store, e.g. all actions should be defined *within* the action brackets - obviously.

Nevertheless took me a while to figure this out, because stores can get complex and defining actions on the root level of a store will not raise any errors.